# Javascript dynamic varible in $.each statement

Tags: javascript

I have a catalog of items which are all shown through a ***while loop*** all items have a description, which can be copied with the ***ZeroClipboard*** plugin.

I need to make the code below create a client for each of the ***.itemDescriptionContainer***'s. So that i copies the correct data.

I created an attribute with the id of the item containing the description ***.itemDescriptionContainer***

---

***Current Code - I tried (and not working)***

***HTML***

```
//While Loop
<div class="itemDescriptionContainer">
    <div id="copy-button" data-clipboard-target="copyDescription">Copy Description<div>
    <div id="copyDescription">
</div>
//endwhile
```

***Javascript***

```
$(".itemDescriptionContainer").each(function(index){
    var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-button") );

    client.on("ready", function(readyEvent) {
        client.on("aftercopy", function(event) {
            event.target.innerHTML = "Description Copied!";
        });
    });
});
```

---

***The following code is kinda working, it only copies the description of the first item in the whileloop**

***HTML***

```
//While Loop
<div class="itemDescriptionContainer" data-itemID="{{{$item->id}}}">
    <div id="copy-button-{{{$item->id}}}" data-clipboard-target="copyDescription-{{{$item->id}}}">Copy Description<div>
    <div id="copyDescription-{{{$item->id}}}">
</div>
//endwhile
```

***Javascript***

```
    var itemID = $(this).attr('data-itemID');
    // Attach itemID to client somehow to make a client instance unique.

    var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-button") );

    client.on("ready", function(readyEvent) {
        client.on("aftercopy", function(event) {
            event.target.innerHTML = "Description Copied!";
        });
    });
```

Comment: please write whole document.

Comment: what are you expecting to happen with your code, what is actually happneing?

Comment: please clarify what you want exactly, starting by what you want ,what you've  tried and what is going wrong

Comment: The ***aftercopy*** is a function used by ZeroClipboard

Comment: I added some more, the first part is function on the first entry of data, but not on the rest of the elements in the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with the use of the window function, i hope some can find this useful.

```
$(".itemDescriptionContainer").each(function(){
   var itemID = $(this).attr('data-itemID');

   // Copy Item Description
   var dynamic = window["client" + itemID] = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById("copy-button-"+itemID));

   dynamic.on("ready", function(readyEvent){
      dynamic.on("aftercopy", function(event){
         event.target.innerHTML = "Description copied!";
      });
   });

});
```